# Are too many filters bad? + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started using 'flog' and 'flay' gems to bring down code complexity and duplication. As a result, some of my controllers started having a lot of before and after filters. For an example, even if one line of code is repeated in multiple methods of a controller, i started shifting that code to a before_filter. flog n flay do say that my code is optimized but i was wondering whether it really is? Do so many filters bring down execution time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily think so, but I haven't tested it.  One way to ensure efficiency is to add conditions on filters.  For example:  `before_filter :store_image, :unless => :has_image?`

This way a model would only execute `store_image` if no image is present.

Comment: yes, i agree that conditions need to be added to filters, but sometimes as functionality gets complex, u start loading data using filters(ideal way) but then your controller has a lot of filters.